# Conditional Concatenation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a dataframe with the below structure :

```
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+------+
|      date|market|metric|aggregator_Value|type    |rank  |
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+------+
|2018-08-05|    m1|   16 |              m1|median  |  1   |
|2018-08-03|    m1|    5 |              m1|median  |  2   |
|2018-08-01|    m1|   10 |              m1|mean    |  3   |
|2018-08-05|    m2|   35 |              m2|mean    |  1   |
|2018-08-03|    m2|   25 |              m2|mean    |  2   |
|2018-08-01|    m2|    5 |              m2|mean    |  3   |
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+------+
```

In this dataframe  the rank column is calculated on the order of date and groupings of the market column.
Like this

```
val w_rank = Window.partitionBy("market").orderBy(desc("date"))
val outputDF2=outputDF1.withColumn("rank",rank().over(w_rank))
```

I want to extract the concatenated value of the metric column in the output dataframe when the rank=1 , with the condition that if the type="median" in rank=1 row is  then concatenate all the metric values with that market .Otherwise if the type="mean" in rank=1 row , then concatenate only the previous 2 metric values .Like this

```
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+---------+
|      date|market|metric|aggregator_Value|type    |result   |
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+---------+
|2018-08-05|    m1|   16 |              m1|median  |10|5|16  |
|2018-08-05|    m2|   35 |              m1|mean    |25|35    |
+----------+------+------+----------------+--------+---------+
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nullify column `metric` according to the specific condition and apply `collect_list` followed by `concat_ws` to get the wanted result, as show below:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2018-08-05", "m1", 16, "m1", "median", 1),
  ("2018-08-03", "m1",  5, "m1", "median", 2),
  ("2018-08-01", "m1", 10, "m1", "mean",   3),
  ("2018-08-05", "m2", 35, "m2", "mean",   1),
  ("2018-08-03", "m2", 25, "m2", "mean",   2),
  ("2018-08-01", "m2",  5, "m2", "mean",   3)
).toDF("date", "market", "metric", "aggregator_value", "type", "rank")

val win_desc = Window.partitionBy("market").orderBy(desc("date"))
val win_asc = Window.partitionBy("market").orderBy(asc("date"))

df.
  withColumn("rank1_type", first($"type").over(win_desc.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))).
  withColumn("cond_metric", when($"rank1_type" === "mean" && $"rank" > 2, null).otherwise($"metric")).
  withColumn("result", concat_ws("|", collect_list("cond_metric").over(win_asc))).
  where($"rank" === 1).
  show
// +----------+------+------+----------------+------+----+----------+-----------+-------+
// |      date|market|metric|aggregator_value|  type|rank|rank1_type|cond_metric| result|
// +----------+------+------+----------------+------+----+----------+-----------+-------+
// |2018-08-05|    m1|    16|              m1|median|   1|    median|         16|10|5|16|
// |2018-08-05|    m2|    35|              m2|  mean|   1|      mean|         35|  25|35|
// +----------+------+------+----------------+------+----+----------+-----------+-------+
```